# VUEJS : How to display data from an API that starts with a number variable?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, ionic-framework

[api structure looks like this (i cropted the photo for it contains personal information)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGYXc.png)

API looks like this:

`[ 0: {"id" : "1234", "name" : "John Doe",...} 1: {"id" : "5678", "name" : "Jane Doe",...} 3: {"id" : "9101", "name" : "Hanna Doe",...} ]`

Axios method looks like this:

`var profile = axios.get("api link here");`

`this.profile = profile.data;`

V-for loop looks like this:

`<ion-item v-for="item in profile" :key="item">`

`<ion-label>{{item[0]["name"]}}</ion-label>`

`</ion-item>`

I am using VueJS v-for to loop through the api, but I only want to access specific data from the API. The info of John Doe, for example.

I already tried something like:

`item[0]["name"]`

`item[0].name`

I have a **mounted()** also.

but it doesn't work inside the v-for statement. It doesn't display anything. Please help.

Comment: The example api data you posted is invalid..  Most likely it is not an array, but an object with properties 0, 1, 2, etc.   You can convert that to a normal array with: data = Object.values(data);   If this does not fix the problem then you will need to update the question to show the actual (valid) data structure.

Comment: @Yogi I attached a screenshot of the API structure.

Comment: @Yogi I tried that but it displayed all the names or ids within the API. My problem is to display only the data based on user profile selection. For example, when I click Name 1, it will only display his information (one array of objects).

Comment: @Yogi I tried to use v-if just like the others suggested but I don't know how to use a dynamic variable inside the conditional statement. Example, instead of `v-if="0 === index"`, I wanna use `v-if="id === index"` where id has a dynamic value (it can be 0, 1, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

When using `v-for` in this case `v-for="item in profile"` you are assigning the value of each element in that array to the key of **item**,

so it means that item equals to `{"id" : "1234", "name" : "John Doe",...}` and you dont have to access it by `item[0]`,as i mentioned before item is already an object,so in order to access the needed values just directly write the object properties

`item.name` and etc..

Comment: Hello. I tried this but it displays all the names that are inside the API. What if I only want to display one name or one data?

Comment: @SINEADAJAX then use `v-if` to only render the first index of the loop. I recommend doing something like `v-for="(item, index) in profile` then `v-if="index === 0"` on `ion-label`

Comment: @SINEADAJAX then you dont need v-for, after you get data with axios 
just write `<ion-label>{{ profile[0].name }}</ion-label>`

Comment: I tried the v-if and it's working. However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to change index value based on user selection. Instead of `v-if="index === 0"`, I want to use a value stored in a variable called id like `v-if="index === id"`. But, it doesn't seem to be working. The goal of my project is to display the information of each person inside the api based on the selected name.

Comment: @SINEADAJAX add eventlistener to the logic of selecting name, it can be added on input or some button or any other type of filter which you would prefer for your project,and using computed properties return the result of looping through array something like
`return profile.filter(item => item.id === id)`